# How do I know if GL_OES_standard_derivatives is supported by the device?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, glsles

I would like to use a GLSL ES shader which requires

```
#if GL_OES_standard_derivatives
#   extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif
```

within my libgdx (Android/iOS) app. How can I determine whether a device supports this or not?

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL ES has glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) which returns a space separated list. If you can access Java on Android, you can use the static method of the GLES10 class like this:

```
bool is_supported()
{
    return GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_EXTENSIONS).contains("GL_OES_standard_derivatives");
}
```

If you're using GLES 2.0 or higher, use GLES20 instead.

On iOS if you have access to C, you could do:

```
bool is_supported()
{
    return strstr(glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), "GL_OES_standard_derivatives") != NULL;
}
```